# Reducing the Dimensionality of the Sphere in terms of the Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, spherical-coordinates, spheres

The $n$-sphere can be written as an $(n-1)$-sphere fibered over an interval
$$
ds^2_{\Omega_n} = d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta\;d\Omega_{n-1}^2.
$$
In these coordinates, when we impose that we keep $\theta$ fixed at a certain value (e.g. $\theta = \pi/2$) the resulting space becomes effectively that of the $(n-1)$-sphere
$$
ds^2_{\Omega_n} \Big|_{\theta=\pi/2} = ds^2_{\Omega_{(n-1)}}
$$
I am trying to understand this statement from a group theoretical point of view.

The $n$-sphere is a symmetric space and is equivalent to the coset
$$
S^n = \frac{SO(n+1)}{SO(n)},
$$
What would now be the procedure in terms of the algebra that is equivalent to `keeping $\theta$ fixed'?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what do want. Are you looking for an reasonable, explicit subspace $U \subset SO(n + 1)$ whose image under the canonical projection $SO(n + 1) \to SO(n + 1) / SO(n)$ can be identified with a (great) hypersphere $S^{n - 1}$ in $S^n$?